# Cómo cargar texto desde un archivo txt en kivy

Tags: android, python, archivo, programación-móvil, kivy

estoy tratando de hacer una app que cargue texto desde un archivo txt. El programa me funciona en el ordenador de escritorio, pero al cargarlo en el móvil, la aplicación del kivy Launcher hace como que carga mi proyecto pero luego se cierra.
El código de python es el siguiente:

```
# config
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'system')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    f = open("Prueba.txt","r")
    filetext = f.read()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()
    def on_pause(self): 
        return True
    def on_resume(self): 
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'): 
    myApp().run()
```

El archivo design.kv:

```
<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textInp2
            text: root.filetext
            multiline: True
            readonly: True
            background_color: 0.92,0.89,0.75,1
            on_focus: self.focus = False
```

¿Por qué no me la carga el Kivy Launcher en el móvil y si se me carga en el ordenador? ¿Qué tengo que hacer para que se me cargue en el móvil?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Es casi seguro un error de encodeo, kivy en android usa Python 2.7 por el momento ( el uso de Python 3 está ahora mismo en fase experimental en Android)¿Que codificación usas en tu Pruebas.txt? ¿Es ASCII, ANSI (Latin-1), UTF-8? Si lo has creado con el Bloc de Notas de Windows será ANSI si no lo has cambiado al guardar.

Comment: @FJSevilla: El archivo design.kv lo he hecho con el notepad++ mientras que el archivo "Pruebas.txt" lo he hecho el bloc de notas de W7

Comment: Vale, el archivo design.kv debe ser UTF-8, está bien como lo haces. El problema está en Pruebas.txt. La codificacion por defecto del Bloc es ANSI, espera un momento voy a crear una respuesta a ver si es lo que yo creo y puedes abrirlo.

Comment: @FJSevilla: Con el notepad++ he cambiado el archivo, "Pruebas.txt" a UTF-8, parece que Kivy Launcher me lo carga, pero al pulsar el botón que ha de cargar el texto se me cierra el Kivy Launcher.

Comment: Edita la pregunta con el código actual si es posible (en tu código no usas botones para cargar el texto)

Comment: @FJSevilla: Si lo siento, sin querer he mezclado el código. El código que vale es el que está publicado. Voy a probarlo con el código que está publicado, habiendo hecho el cambio en la codificación del archivo "Pruebas.txt"

Comment: @FJSevilla: Vale, era lo que decías, ya me funciona. Publica tu respuesta para que pueda marcarla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kivy usa por el momento Python 2.7 en Android (el uso de Python 3 está en fase de experimentación y posiblemente llege en algún momento). El error se debe a que estas intentando leer un archivo con codificación diferente a UTF-8.

Internamente kivy convierte el texto a UTF-8 antes de mostralo en el Text Input usando el módulo codec de la biblioteca standar de Python. Si el archivo está codificado en Latin-1, como son los creado por defecto por el Bloc de Notas de Windows se produce un error del tipo:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 0: unexpected end of data
>   ....
>   return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)

El problema es que en Android esto no lo vemos al no disponer de la consola y en Python 3 si funciona sin problemas. La solución puede variar, o bién usamos una codificación UTF-8 para el archivo o usamos la que queramos pero lo decodificamos explícitamente en el código:

```
f= open('Pruebas.txt', 'rb')
filtext = f.read().decode('Latin-1')
```

En este caso lo abrimos como archivo binario y lo decodificamos, Se podria usar el módulo `io` o `codec` también.

Si aparecen caracteres raros al final de cada linea en Android se debe a que windows usa como final de linea `\n\r` mientras que unix usa `\n`. La solución es abrir en modo universal `'U'`. En Python 3 está marcado como deprecated pero es válido para Python 2:

```
f = open('Prueba.txt', 'rU')
filetext = f.read()
```

o si usamos un archivo de texto no UTF-8 algo así:

```
f = open('Prueba.txt', 'U')
filetext = f.read().decode('Latin-1')
```